# MvvmCross v5 Navigation (MvxNavigationService)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, navigation, mvvmcross

I am migrating to MvvmCross 5 and I want to start implementing the navigation change using the MvxNavigationService.

Currently I use custom presenters to do things like navigate to a view then take the previous view out of the hierarchy. I assume I don't need custom presenters with the new navigation service.

Is it possible to do this with the navigation service?

Also I would like to navigate to a view but build up a navigation stack for it.
For example say I have three views

Home Page
Item List Page
Item Details Page

What I would like to do is go from the Home page to the Item Detail Page directly, but when I close the Item Detail Page, the Item List Page would be displayed.

E.g. when I do navigation
**Home Page -> Item Details Page**
What I really want is the navigation stack to be built as follows
**Home Page -> Item List Page -> Item Detail Page**

The documentation seems to suggest that using the Uri scheme, this would be possible, but I'm not sure how.

Is this possible, if so is it possible to direct me to an example.

Comment: You can use your navigation from "home page" to "item details page" (marked with "no history" in the view) and then navigate to "Item List page".  As marked with "no history", the "details" page won't stay in the navigation stack

Comment: Thanks. How do I mark it "no history"?

Comment: Here is an example that you need to put on top of your Activity as Attribute [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned I want to be able to achive this using the MvxNavigationService, As in some cases I don't want to remove it from the history